# Sorting an array alphabetically by one element - possible solution is to sort by another array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have an array of `songs` that contains:

`name` `artist` `album` `genre`

The array is completely random at the moment.

### Aim

I want the user to be able to view the contents separately by name, or by artist etc..

### Attempt

I recall, in another language (`php`) I could create a new array of, for example, `artists` and then sort the `songs` array by the `artists`. This is good in theory but how to implement?

I created a sorted array of `artists`, like this:

```
    songs.each { |member|
               artists << member.artist
      }

artists.sort!
```

This works great, and outputs all the `artists` to the screen alphabetically when testing.

My problem is how would I sort the `songs` array by the `artists` array? I.e. the `songs` would be sorted by the `artists`

### Question

Is there an easier way to sort the `songs` array alphabetically?

Ultimately, it would be ideal to have an `name` array, `artist` array, `album` array, `genre` array, each of which would have the same contents as the `songs` array, but sorted alphabetically by the relevant field.

Thanks for any help.

### Example

Input:

`Songs` =

```
[['Song A','B Artist'],['Song D','A Artist'],['Song D','C Artist']]
```

Example Output

`Artist` =

`[['A Artist','Song D'],['B Artist','Song A'],['C Artist','Song D']]`

Comment: can you give an example please:
input array and output array.

Comment: @sahildhankhar example added..

Comment: `songs.sort_by {|song| song[0]}`  or `songs.sort_by {|song| song[1]}`
whatever index of the song you want to sort on. works for you?

Answer (score 2):

There's [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
songs = [
  {name: "Like a Rolling Stone", artist: "Bob Dylan"},
  {name: "(I Can't Get No) Satisfaction", artist: "The Rolling Stones"},
  {name: "Imagine", artist: "John Lennon" }
]

songs.sort_by { |song| song[:name] }
#=> [
#     {:name=>"(I Can't Get No) Satisfaction", :artist=>"The Rolling Stones"},
#     {:name=>"Imagine", :artist=>"John Lennon"},
#     {:name=>"Like a Rolling Stone", :artist=>"Bob Dylan"}
#   ]

songs.sort_by { |song| song[:artist] }
#=> [
#     {:name=>"Like a Rolling Stone", :artist=>"Bob Dylan"},
#     {:name=>"Imagine", :artist=>"John Lennon"},
#     {:name=>"(I Can't Get No) Satisfaction", :artist=>"The Rolling Stones"}
#   ]
```

Comment: Thanks .. interesting answer, Although I have no idea how I would implement this - very much a novice

Comment: Please be more specific, where are you stuck?

Comment: I attempted to sort my array using `songs.sort_by { |song| song[:artist] }` as you suggested, and I get this error: `undefined method '[]'`. However - I suspect that your answer requires me to build my array in a different manner - is that right? I am not familiar with enumerable array

Comment: I should rephrase that - How would I create the array so that I could used the Enumerable Sort by? My `songs` array is 1876 elements long!

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem. `sort_by` should work fine even with much larger arrays.